# Replace height="***" stars

Tags: php, replace, size, height, width

I want to replace 'width' and 'height' on my site.

For example:

```
width="600" height="365"
```

I want to change the width and height, to

```
width="712" height="475"
```

I can do this with.

```
$replace =str_replace('width="600" height="365"', 'width="712" height="475"', $replace)
```

The problem is, the width and height is not always 600 and 365 they might be something else. like.

```
width="222" height="333"
```

Anything... I'm looking for something like this:

```
$replace =str_replace('width="***" height="***"', 'width="712" height="475"', $replace)
```

That replaces anything inside the width and height to '712' and '475'.

Anyone has any idea how to can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: how do the original values got into the html in the first place?

Comment: Gordon@ file_get_contents from anther site. Thanks.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$replace = preg_replace('~width="\d*" height="\d*"~', 'width="712" height="475"', $replace);
```

Answer (score 3):

While you're better off setting the width and height once programmatically in your PHP, you can use a regular expression to find and replace it later if you must.

```
$replace = preg_replace('/width="\d+" height="\d+"/', 'width="712" height="475"', $replace);
```

Comment: Samir Talwar@ It works, thanks! But what's the different between this and the one above?

Comment: @Muazam: This only replaces if both width and height have at least a number, mine replaces even if they are empty - other than that they are exactly the same.

Comment: @Muazam: They're practically identical. We must have posted at the same time.